# Draw arrows between several combined screenshots

Tags: screenshot

How to combine several screenshots and draw arrows between them? I found I can draw arrows by [flameshot](https://github.com/flameshot-org/flameshot) app but can't combine several screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of graphics editors that can do what you want. Import your screenshots, add the arrows and export the result to a new graphics file in the format you need.

Next to the very powerful and well known *Gimp*, more simple and lightweight bitmap editors can be found in Software. You can also achieve the same result in vector graphics programs. These invariably offer the option to export the result to a bitmap graphic. *Draw* or *Impress* from the LibreOffice suite could be used. Also *Inkscape* can be used.

Comment: I used GIMP but didn't find an arrow tool there. After your answer googled this thing https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118340 and it helped. Thanks :)